# Azure API Management and HMAC

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I wanted to use **Azure API** management for exposing our existing *APIs* to third-party developers. Azure API management provides a developer portal where third parties can sign-in and obtain subscription keys. The subscription key is then supposed to be passed with every request as query string parameter or along with **POST** parameters.

This seems to be a concern since there is a possibility of someone easily getting access to this key if they can intercept **HTTP** traffic. The common mechanism is to generate HMAC of the request using client secret and sending it along with the request to ensure integrity and authenticity of the request and not send the client secret along with the request.

- Is it possible to enable **HMAC** based integrity checks on Azure API Management?
- Also is it possible to configure **Azure API** Management to send back the response with HMAC so that client as well can verify that the response is coming from a reliable source?

Answer (score 1):

On the matter of calculating a message authentication code, what would you like to use as input for the hashing function - just the URL, the whole body, something else?

Alternately you can use the client certification authentication policy for added security, but I understand it is not a real replacement for HMAC:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/061702a7-3a78-472b-a54a-f3b1e332490d#ClientCertificate

Comment: You can also use the JWT token validation policy:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/034febe3-465f-4840-9fc6-c448ef520b0f#ValidateJWT

Your app will produce the JWT token with a secret and then the APIM proxy will validate it either by using the signing key or by calling an OpenID configuration endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

https is supported between your client and Azure API Management.

Comment: Yes but HTTPS won't be sufficient to prevent request replay attacks . HMAC can help implement request timeouts

Comment: good point, can you please add a request in our UserVoice: http://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management